# Wasteland horror series in trade paperback

Tags: dc, horror

DC published an anthology horror series in the '90s called *Wasteland*.  I have never seen a collected edition of this series.  My question is: has the entire series, or any part of it, ever been collected in trade paperback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All signs point to "**No.**"

Searching just brings up people lamenting the fact that there is no collected edition.

This [interview with creator, John Ostrander](http://www.factualopinion.com/the_factual_opinion/2012/03/wasteland-the-john-ostrander-interview.html) is from 2012, and states:

> It’s worth mentioning that Wasteland has never been collected and may very well remain out of print. I’m not sure if the world of comics would be any more inviting to such a series today than it was back in 1987, but don’t let public taste deprive you of these great comics. Every page is worth seeking out and with minimal effort, you’ll discover that I’m not wrong.

I can't find anything more recent that contradicts that statement.